# Is this why there can only be three pairings out of 4 people?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am unsure whether the below logic is accurate as to why you can only form three pairings of four people:

Every pairing can be completely described by whom a single person is paired with. Given this, we could certainly use the same person to identify each pairing, therefore, the question of the number of pairings there are devolves into  how many people can be paired with a single person out of the four, which is $3.$

I am feeling shaky about this due to not being confident that we can model each of the pairings using only whom a single person is paired with; how we rigorously justify this further?

Comment: Your reasoning is sound. If you insist on formalizing it, define a bijection between your set of pairings and your set of candidates to be paired with your selected person.

Comment: When OP is saying "three pairings out of 4 people" , $3$ will not be "Accurate" , @AnneBauval , What Op should say is something like "Candidate X has three pairings with 3 other people". When we want to make Pairs out of $n$ Candidates , then [A] we should either Indicate that we are going to fix 1 Candidate X (we get $n-1$ Pairs) or [B] we should not indicate that we are going to fix a Candidate (we get $n(n-1)/2$ Pairs) which then will be totally unambiguous.

Comment: To me and to the answerer at least,  OP is "unambiguous" *as it is*, and 3 is "accurate". @Prem

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb and I'm not understanding the premise, but with 4 symbols you can form 6 different unordered pairs. If we have A,B,C,D, then all the pairings are: AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD

Comment: @Serkratos121 I understand what you mean but most probably the issue is here: in how many ways can we split up 4 persons in two pairs?

Comment: Seeing the various Interpretations going on here , between myself , you , Serkratos & drhab , & the OP , the Wording seems ambiguous here , @AnneBauval , & I am not sure what OP is looking for. In Case the Answer by ConMan is what OP is looking for , then the Same logic will not hold when Pairing with 6 or 8 or more Candidates. What I mean : "Every pairing can be completely described by whom a single person is paired with" is not true in general Case. It is Co-Incidentally true when we have $2+2=4$ Candidates.

Comment: See [How many ways are there to break the people into two teams of two?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526236/how-many-ways-are-there-to-break-the-people-into-two-teams-of-two/4526264#4526264).

Comment: Regarding the concern you express in your last paragraph: can you write an algorithm that builds a pairing explicitly, given only the name that the first person is paired to? If so, can you prove that your algorithm is correct? (or convince yourself that your algorithm is correct.) That should make you more confident that *"we can model each of the pairings using only whom a single person is paired with"*

Answer (score 3):

If you want to map it out, it's pretty simple. Let's label our set of people $\{A, B, C, D\}$.

To pair people off, we can look at who $A$ is paired with. There are three choices - $B, C$ and $D$. Notice that these are **mutually exclusive** and **exhaustive** options, meaning that the total number of ways to pair the set up can be found by adding together:

1. The number of ways to pair the set up once $A$ is paired with $B$;
2. The number of ways to pair the set up once $A$ is paired with $C$; and
3. The number of ways to pair the set up once $A$ is paired with $D$.

However, also notice that as soon as $A$ is paired with someone, there are only 2 people left in the set and so they must be paired with each other. In other words, for each of the 3 partitions we've identified, there is exactly one pairing of the entire set.

Therefore, there are exactly 3 ways to create pairs within the group of 4 people, and each way is uniquely defined by which member of the set is $A$'s partner. Of course there's nothing special about $A$, so in the end you can always define a pairing in the set by identifying the partner of any single arbitrary member of the set.

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is sound. If you insist on formalizing it, define a bijection between your set $X$ of pairings and your set $Y$ of $3$ candidates to be paired with your selected person:

Let $1,2,3,4$ be your four persons and select for instance $1,$ so that $Y=\{2,3,4\}.$

Define$$f:Y\to X,\quad y\mapsto\{\{1,y\},\{1,y\}^\complement\}$$
where $A^\complement$ denotes the complement $\{1,2,3,4\}\setminus A,$
and
$$g:X\to Y,\quad P\mapsto\text{the unique }y\text{ such that }\{1,y\}\in P.$$
Then, $g\circ f={\rm id}_Y$ and $f\circ g={\rm id}_X,$ hence $f,g$ are mutually inverse bijections, so that $|X|=|Y|=3.$

But honestly, I find no gain in such a formalization.

Edit (per comment): in order check that for every $y\in Y,$ $f(y)\in X,$ just notice that $|\{1,y\}^\complement|=4-|\{1,y\}|=2.$

Comment: In my opinion, this formalisation makes it more obscure and hides the things that need to be checked (for instance, that $\{1,y\}^\complement$ defines a pair); perhaps an alternative would be to define $f$ not by a formula, but by a table, with 2; 3; 4 in one column and (1,2),(3,4); (1,3),(2,4); (1,4),(2,3) in the second column, to show that $f$ is well defined and a bijection between two finite sets of three elements.

Comment: @Stef I agree it is not satisfying (even worse: no answer can be more satisfying than the OP itself). I also thought about a table, but this implicitely includes a *direct* exhaustive enumeration of the pairings, which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Hmm. Yes I agree. I guess the OP's main concern is the one they express in their last paragraph, but I don't know how to write a formal and satisfying justification for that.

Answer (score 2):

If we want a group of $4$ persons to be split up in two pairs then we can start with choosing the *first* pair which boils down to selecting $2$ out of $4$.

So there are $\binom42=6$ ways to do that.

Then the $2$ persons that are not chosen automatically form the *second* pair.

But we must not overlook that here an *ordening* of two pairs is involved (first,second).

If we are not interested in this ordening then outcome $6$ must be divided by $2$ to repair double counting, and we end up with $3$ possibilities for two pairs.

---

IMV the formulation of the question can be improved to avoid confusion. This is affirmed by the comments on the question.